# How to deal with degeneracies in data

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, generative-models

I am working with a dataset where I want to predict some features (let's call them G) from some other features (we'll call them W). The problem is that there is no one-to-one mapping from W to G. In other words, many points with the same or similar values in W may have many different possible values in G. The end goal of this project would be to specify a W-vector and have it spit out many/all relevant/corresponding G-vectors. What are some good strategies that could be used to deal with this degeneracy in the data? (I should mention that there is a deterministic mapping from G to W, but not from W to G)

Comment: How many possible values for G are there? Are they always a fixed size or could they be infinite?

Comment: The dimensions of G are continuous ranges, so they could be infinite, but in theory some of these points would be more interesting/relevant than others (i.e. if two points very very close to each other in G-space also happen to be very close in W-space, that is perhaps less interesting to us than if there are two points far apart in G-space that end up near each other in W-space)